# Cosmicmind/Material: difference between NavigationController and ToolbarController

Tags: swift3, cosmicmind

I'm working on a app that is written with swift3 in Xcode8.
My app implements the Cosmicmind-material-framework.

While the working i tried to understand what the difference between NavigationController and ToolbarController is. (maybe someone can additionaly explain the difference to PageTabBarController, too)

I don't really get it because it seems that the navigationController contains a toolbarController. 
So why should i use both if i can only use the navigationController and prepare all "toolbar-items" there.

Shortly to the app:

- NavigationDrawerController

  - NavigationController

    1. Site 1
    2. Site 2
    3. PageTabBarController

       1. Site Red
       2. Site Blue
       3. Site Yellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good question.

The main difference between a NavigationController and ToolbarController is that a NavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController and gives you all the benefits of that class while allowing you to customize the look and feel as if you would a ToolbarController.

The ToolbarController provides a different type of flow, one that transitions the `rootViewController` using the `transition` method between view controllers. It also provides a floating view controller that can effectively be used in many ways.

Like the ToolbarController, the PageTabBarController inherits from the RootController, which provides the same rootViewController transitioning, but by default offers a UIPageViewController as the initial rootViewController.

So what is the point of all these different controllers? The main design reason is to allow you to stack view controllers that have these special controls in order to create more complex navigational architectures without the fuss of maintaining their organization. Each is accessible within the hierarchy while managing their own code complexities. The user has the perception that they are all working together seamlessly.

A good example of this is the [CardTableView sample project](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Graph/CardTableView), which also shows how to layout Cards within the PageTabBarController using TableViews that have dynamic heights based on content. For the most part, the entire UI is driven using persisted data powered by Graph.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: many thanks at first for the fast response 

So did the first section mean that there is no need for a ToolbarController if is use the NavigationController (and prepare all the "toolbar-items" in the NavCtrl)?

Comment: Yes that is correct :) You only need one or the other based on your navigational needs.

Comment: Great, that mean that i've done right till now :D i have another question x) at my constellation (what u see above) i didn't have a direct connection between the NavigationController and the PageTabBarController. My problem now is, that the PageTabBarController affects the NavigationController and clear all navigationCtrl-items and I don't understand why x(.

Comment: Hmm... I am not sure I fully understand. How does the PageTabBarController affect the NavigationController, you mean when you add it, you no longer see the `navigationItems` in the NavigationController, which were set in a previous view controller?

Comment: please forget my last comment.. i had a little "error of reasoning" x). My Problem is that i modify/add `navigationItems` like `navigationItem.title`(in `SiteRedViewController`) but the `navigationController` is still empty. According the debugger all my modifications r executed.... but.... yeah.... nothing changed. however... if i do all these changes in the `PageTabBarController`, it works.. but no matter where i use `navigationItem`, the reference of it should be the same... or not? // ps. i'm really sorry for my bad english...

Comment: okay..... the modifing works if I use `pageTabBarController?.navigationItem.title  = "crazyTitle"`

Comment: Yes, the reason is that it works from the pageTabBarController is that the pageTabBarController is the direct child (rootViewController) of the NavigationController. The rootViewController of the pageTabBarController is a direct child of pageTabBarController so it is one step further down in the view hierarchy for the NavigationController to detect. So you can do what you did pageTabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "crazyTitle", or place it in a subclass of the PageTabBarController. :) This is why you see in my samples subclasses like AppPageTabBarController.